# What is a safe way to allow REST APIs to be public?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my website, people can see images given from REST APIs without login. I want to make some of my APIs not to require a user token. So, I had some research and I found the way below.

Since I need to use this way for production, I want to make sure if it is a safe way. The stores that will be given from the API have just store data such as name, urls, description, and images. Any of them are not related to any users.

Is it okay for me to use in production? Just so you know, I use Django REST Framework to serve data to frontend and use React js to show them in frontend side.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
class ListAllStores(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_stores = Store.objects.all()
        serializer = StoreSerializer(all_stores, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something link sending user type on header of each request.
And for the API without token send userType as anonymous or something like that
And for the API with token send userType  as customer or something like that.

Create a method which will be called first thing from the each end points and validate the Request header.

If you want to make it more general you can map this end point and type of user as meta data setting, So next time if you have some '/image' end point which was allowed only to the customer user type but now you want it should be allowed to anon also so that can be easily done using that meta data file without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit by using `AllowAny` permission class, which will let public access to that endpoint.

```
from rest_framework import permissions, views

class ListAllStores(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.AllowAny,
    )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_stores = Store.objects.all()
        serializer = StoreSerializer(all_stores, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Comment: As a side note, your code can be refactored to use `views.ListAPIView` and declare this class attributes `serializer_class=StoreSerializer` and `queryset=Store.objects.all()`

Comment: Can you explain what is different between `permission_classes` as an attribute inside the class and `permission_classes` as a decorator? Do they work differently? Also, do I not need `authentication_classes `?

Comment: decorators are usually used with a function based view toghether with @api_view, class based views are using class attribute for that.